# Player starts to jump on planet that has it's own gravity when moving south

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a planet that has its own gravity and I can move around the top just fine but when I go towards the south the player starts to jump up and down for some reason and I'm not sure as to why any thoughts on how I can fix it?
[Video of problem](https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/183q3Z1h1p1k2S0k2I0z/Screen%20recording%202017-09-27%20at%2006.38.20%20PM.mp4?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=2782700)

Planet Gravity

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
    {
        Vector3 difference = this.gameObject.transform.position - other.gameObject.transform.position;

        float dist = difference.magnitude;
        Vector3 gravityDirection = difference.normalized;
        Vector3 gravityVector = (gravityDirection * gravity) / (dist * dist);
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(gravityVector, ForceMode.Acceleration);

    }
}
```

Movement

```
    void Update ()
{
    ////Defaults to the left Stick
   float hAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); 
   float vAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");


    Vector3 NextDir = new Vector3(hAxis, 0, vAxis);

    float deadzone = 0.25f;
    //Vector2 stickInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    if (NextDir.magnitude < deadzone)
    {
        NextDir = Vector3.zero;


    }
    else
    {
        NextDir = NextDir.normalized * ((NextDir.magnitude - deadzone) / (1 - deadzone));
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(NextDir);
        transform.Translate(NextDir.x * Time.deltaTime * 5, NextDir.y * Time.deltaTime * 5, NextDir.z * Time.deltaTime * 5, Space.Self);


    }
 }
}
```

Player Orientation Script

```
    void LateUpdate()
{

    Vector3 dir = planet.transform.position - transform.position;
    dir.Normalize();
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, dir * 100, out hit))
    {

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, hit.normal) * transform.rotation;

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you turn off gravity on the player's rigidbody?

Comment: What is your intention with the line `transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(NextDir);`?